# Hide everything else and only show one div

Tags: jquery

There are multiple items in a div. Each item has a button and info div. When clicking on title in any div, I want to slide up or fade out everything, want to display only the info of that div in kind of lightbox style.

Here's what I'm trying and it does not work. It slides up everything on click, but does not show the info.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner">

        <div class="box">
            <div class="button"></div>
            <div class="info">Info for box 1</div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="button"></div>
            <div class="info">Info for box 2</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    width: 500px;
    background: yellow;
    padding: 20px;
}

.box{
    margin-bottom: 20px;    
}

.info{
    display: none;
}

.button{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.wrap').on('click','.button',function(){

    $('.inner').slideUp(400);
    $(this).closest('.info').slideDown(400);

});
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/a7wwz/

Answer (score 1):

Or try this

```
$('.wrap').on('click','.button',function(){
    $('.inner>div>div').slideUp(400);
    $(this).next('.info').slideDown(400);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a7wwz/4/

Your original version did not work because you use `.slideup()` on a container whose element you want to have visible afterwards. In my version I simply slideup only the `div`s of the lowest level inside the container `.inner`.

And, of course, `closest()` looks upwards for the closest parent. What you really meant was `next()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.wrap').on('click','.button',function(){

    var $info = $(this).next('.info').stop(true, true).slideDown(400);
    $('.info').not($info).stop(true, true).slideUp();

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YX97n/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I said, I want to hide everything else in the .inner div. In your demo the button of the hidden div is visible.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('.wrap').on('click', '.button', function () {
   $('.inner *').not($(this).parent()).slideUp(400);  
   $(this).next().slideDown(400);  
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a7wwz/8/)